# How can I use jQuery in the admin side with my module without breaking everything else?

Tags: magento

```
<default> 
  <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><js>splurgyjs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</js></action>
  </reference>
</default>
```

That's in my layout folder `hello.xml`

So the problem is, I created a new navigation tab with a page that uses jQuery and it works perfect on my custom module page. However, jQuery breaks everything else on every other page like menus stop working and it's conflicting. How can I have the layout show ONLY on my page or how can I include jQuery without conflicts?

Update, I tried Tom's suggestion:

In config.xml:

```
 <layout>
         <updates handle="index_settings">
            <embeds>
                 <file>justin.xml</file>
            </embeds>
         </updates>
     </layout>
```

In justin.xml:

```
<justin_index_settings>
         
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
           <type>js_css</type>
           <name>justin/style.css</name>
        </action>
        </reference>
    </justin_index_settings>
```

Comment: Have you added `jQuery.noConflict()` somewhere? If not, add it. Magento is solely based on prototype, which is already using `$`, thus conflicting with jQuery's version of `$`. That might be your problem.

Comment: I only added it to the file where I had my own jQuery

Comment: That is enough regarding the `$` problem. So you can take that out the equation. You can move the `<reference>` into a custom `<your_own_custom_handle_name>` handle and do a `<update handle="your_own_custom_handle_name>` in each `<yourmodule_controller_action>` within your `hello.xml`. This way jQuery is only loaded within the pages of your own module. As you noticed placing it in `<default>` doesn't load only for all the pages in your module, but all the pages through the system.

Comment: @TimHofman I just tried it and couldn't get it to work. Did I do something wrong? I will update the post.

Comment: I've added an answer with how your XML should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML should be as follows:

```
<my_own_custom_handle>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><js>splurgyjs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</js></action>
    </reference>
</my_own_custom_handle>
```

And then from a `module_controller_action` handle. Taking `<catalog_product_view>` as an example from the `Mage_Catalog` module.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <update handle="my_own_custom_handle" />
</catalog_product_view>
```

This way your Javascript is now only loaded for the page that is generated by the `catalog_product_view` handle, thus only a product detailpage and not the listpage etc.
In your case you only need to adjust this handle to your module handle, probably `justin_index_settings`.